# Custom user control data source

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a custom control that has a DropDownList inside and it's created by CreateUserControl. I'm saving data source directly to dropdown control. After page postbacked my binded data disappear. Should i save/restore my binded data myself in some tricky way?

```
public class EnumDropDownList : UserControl
{
    private readonly DropDownList _ddlSelector;
    private Dictionary<long, string> _dataSource;

    public EnumDropDownList()
    {
        _ddlSelector = new DropDownList();
        _dataSource = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    }


    public object DataSource
    {
        set
        {
            // datasource logic
        }
    }

    public long SelectedValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt64(_ddlSelector.SelectedValue); }
        set { _ddlSelector.SelectedValue = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        _ddlSelector.DataSource = _dataSource;
        _ddlSelector.DataTextField = "Value";
        _ddlSelector.DataValueField = "Key";
        _ddlSelector.DataBind();

        base.DataBind();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "Execution")]
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Add(_ddlSelector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is combination of `UserControl` and `CustomServerControl`.

It could have be a lot easier if you implement one instead of combination.

I created two controls - `UserControl` and `CustomServerControl`.

**UserControl**

Place the dropdownlist to ASPX instead of loading dymaiclally. If you load dynamically, you'll have to take care of persistence of control.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EnumDropDownList.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication2010.EnumDropDownList" %>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" />

public partial class EnumDropDownList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private Dictionary<long, string> _dataSource;

    public EnumDropDownList()
    {
        _dataSource = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    }

    public Dictionary<long, string> DataSource
    {
        set { _dataSource = value; }
    }

    public long SelectedValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt64(DropDownList1.SelectedValue); }
        set { DropDownList1.SelectedValue = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = _dataSource;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Value";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Key";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        base.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Custom Server Control  (it is a lot easier to implement for your case)**

It basically inherits DropDownList web control.

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    public long SelectedInt64Value
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt64(SelectedValue); }
        set { SelectedValue = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public Dictionary<long, string> DataSource
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<long, string>)ViewState["DataSource"]; }
        set { ViewState["DataSource"] = value; }
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        foreach (var item in DataSource)
            Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Value, item.Key.ToString()));

        base.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm5.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2010.WebForm5" %>

<%@ Register Src="EnumDropDownList.ascx" TagName="EnumDropDownList" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="WebApplication2010" Assembly="WebApplication2010" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <uc1:EnumDropDownList ID="EnumDropDownList1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:MyDropDownList id="MyDropDownList1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Dictionary<long, string> dataSource  = new Dictionary<long, string>();
        dataSource.Add(1, "One");
        dataSource.Add(2, "Two");

        EnumDropDownList1.DataSource = dataSource;
        EnumDropDownList1.DataBind();

        MyDropDownList1.DataSource = dataSource;
        MyDropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases I have saved the dataset in a session variable. Whicn can then be referenced after postbacks. Something like this:

```
Session.Add("dataSource", _dataSource);//create the session variable
```

Then you can reference it, depending on the type the data source is (in example I used a datable)

```
_ddlSelector.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dataSource"];
```

Comment: So It's true and I'm missing manual restoring of the data source, but saving this data into the session is not a good idea in the big project.

Comment: Well if you need it to persist, you can cache it in (like the session example) or you can make another call to the database to refresh and then rebind the data.

Comment: But I need to do it on the proper stage, like override LoadControlState or LoadViewState...

Comment: Well it sounds like you already have an idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

THis Is aspx file :

```
                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbCurrency" runat="server" Width="200px" MaxHeight="200px"
                    EmptyMessage="Select a currency" AutoPostBack="true" Filter="Contains" EnableLoadOnDemand="true">
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

This is code Behind :

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                popCurrencyName();              
            }    

    public void popCurrencyName()
                {
                    DataTable dtCurrency = objCurrencyBAL.getCurrency(long.MinValue);

                    if (dtCurrency.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        cmbCurrency.DataSource = dtCurrency;
                        cmbCurrency.DataTextField = "Name";
                        cmbCurrency.DataValueField = "CurrencyId";
                        cmbCurrency.DataBind();
                    }
                }
```

Try this code: